# How can i get all the users and their authorize_key in linux using shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, centos

I am using the following script to get the key count.  But its is not working, is any other method exists? or how should i fix the error?

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in `cat /etc/passwd` ; do\
    echo $i |\
    awk -F: { print `grep -o "ssh-rsa" <<< (cat /home/"$1"/ .ssh/authorized_keys ) | wc -l` }  
done
```

Comment: Do you want to just display all of the keys? Or do you need to show which username has which keys?

Comment: Why a downvote on this one?

Comment: Usually the `.ssh` folder contains known hosts, the public and the private key to your server.

Comment: i dont know why the down vote. @sjsam

Comment: @Praveensivadasan I believe this question meets the requirements as mentioned by [\[ mcve \]](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Not sure why this was downvoted. People who downvote without a comment deprive others of great learning opportunity :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to display the number of keys, you can do this:

```
for homedir in $(awk -F':' '{print $6}' /etc/passwd); do
    [[ -f "${homedir}/.ssh/authorized_keys" ]] && cat "${homedir}/.ssh/authorized_keys"
done
```

To display the counts for each file:

```
for homedir in $(awk -F':' '{print $6}' /etc/passwd); do
    [[ -f "${homedir}/.ssh/authorized_keys" ]] && wc -l "${homedir}/.ssh/authorized_keys"
done
```

To display the counts by username:

```
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
    USERNAME="$(echo "$line" | awk -F: '{print $1}')"
    HOMEDIR="$(echo "$line" | awk -F: '{print $6}')"

    if [[ -f "${HOMEDIR}/.ssh/authorized_keys" ]]; then
        COUNT="$(grep -c 'ssh-' "${HOMEDIR}/.ssh/authorized_keys")"
    else
        COUNT=0
    fi

    echo "${USERNAME} has ${COUNT} keys."
done < "/etc/passwd"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i want the key count of each user.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, is it possible to print the count like this                      awk -F: ' { print "\t\t<user><user_key>${COUNT}</user_key>\n" "\t\t</user>" } ', since i am getting error.

Comment: No problem. There would be no point in using `awk` for that; why not just use `echo`?

Comment: Glad to help, no problem! :)